# How to handle multiple fields in JPA Repository query methods?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have Person -  a JPA entity which has several `@OneToOne` mappings to some other entities like Address, House and Car. I want to find the person who is having a specific house and a specific car in one query.

For example, if we want to find a Person by id, we can use the `findById` method. If we want to find using name, I can define a `findByName` method in my repository.

**My question is**: What will the method signature be if I want to select a person with more than 2 fields set?

I have tried selecting using House by a method `findByHouse()` which is only using one property. I want to select using multiple properties.

Person class :

```
@Entity(name="Person")
@Table(name="person")
@Data
class Person{

@Column(name="HouseID")
Integer houseID;

@Column(name="CarID")
Integer carID;

@Column(name="AddressID")
Integer addressID;

@OneToOne ( fetch= FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinColumn ( name = "houseID" )
private House house;

@OneToOne ( fetch= FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinColumn ( name = "carID" )
private Car car;

@OneToOne ( fetch= FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@JoinColumn ( name = "addressID" )
private Address address;

}
```

Now the Repository:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long>{

   @Query("select p from Person p where p.house.id=:id")
   Person findByHouse(@Param("id")Integer houseID);
}
```

I expect a Person record where the house, car and address is set to a specific value that is passed in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply pass multiple parameters and extend your query with `and` for multiple requirements.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long>{

   @Query("select p from Person p where p.house.id=:houseId and p.carID =:carId")
   Person findByHouseAndCar(@Param("houseId")Integer houseID, @Param("carId")Integer carID);
}
```

Comment: what if I have more than 10 such fields? The method name also need to be that much long or it can be a shorter one?

Comment: as you specify the parameters and query explicit, you can name the method what ever you like.

Comment: Is there any simple way to pass 10 such fields as input to the query?